# How to access property file in Apache Camel with Java DSL?

Tags: apache-camel

I build camel application using org.apache.camel.main.Main class like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    Main main = new Main();

    main.enableHangupSupport();
    main.addRouteBuilder(new MainRoute());
    main.addRouteBuilder(ConfigurationRoute.getloginRoute());
    main.run(args);
}
```

how to include properties file (src/main/resources/prop.properties) in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to configure the Camel properties component for properties placeholders?

http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

We could probably make this easier to configure on the `Main` class so you can configure it to one or more properties files.

I have logged a ticket to make this easier: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10255

What you need to do is to

```
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("prop.properties");

main.bind("properties, pr);
```

Where you create the component and configure it. And then bind it with the id `properties`.

The location is automatic loaded from the classpath, so you do not need `src/main/resources` as prefix.